# SQL query where person has as request for every product

Tags: sql-server

I have a shortcut query where I just counted the total number of products and used count to display that the person has requested that many products. (Which is 8 products)

I want to know if there's an easier way where I wouldn't need to count the the products myself and have the query do it. Basically, replace the 8 with the total amount of products that the database has.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Tb_Consumer.Name 
FROM
    Tb_Consumer, Tb_Product, Tb_Requests
WHERE 
    Tb_Consumer.Con_ID = Tb_Requests.Con_ID
    AND Tb_Requests.Prod_ID = Tb_Product.Prod_ID
GROUP BY 
    Tb_Consumer.Name
HAVING 
    COUNT(Tb_Product.Name) = 8
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery to find the number of products in the `Tb_Product` table:

```
SELECT
    tbc.Name 
FROM Tb_Consumer tbc
INNER JOIN Tb_Request tbr
    ON tbc.Con_ID = tbr.Con_ID
INNER JOIN Tb_Product tbp
    ON tbr.Prod_ID = tbp.Prod_ID
GROUP BY
    tbc.Name
HAVING
    COUNT(tbp.Name) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tb_Product);   -- count products here
```

This assumes that every record in `Tb_Product` corresponds to a single unique product.  If there could be duplication for some reason, then you can count distinct products, e.g.

```
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Name) FROM Tb_Product)
```

Other changes I made include removing `DISTINCT` from the select clause, since the `GROUP BY` should already make each name distinct.  I also refactored your query to remove the commas in the `FROM` clause.  Instead, I use explicit joins between the three tables.